# firebase phone sms authentication in react native and expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am using expo to launch my react native application.
I would like to use the phone authentication for firebase, but from what I am seeing on other posts it will not work without detaching from expo.
Is there another workaround? 
Is it possible to put an iframe inside the app and using the firebase full ui for the authentication?

Comment: Did you find a solution @dor.elmaliach ?

Comment: No unfortunately we are using a mock mail and password for now.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52350212/5245349