# Does expo support firebase phone auth?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am trying to implement firebase phone auth for expo. I have followed many resources on internet but succeeded. Could you please let me know is it possible/available? if it is possible please share some useful resources for expo

thanking you for anticipation.

Comment: Have you got the solution. @Imdad Hussain

Comment: Guys, just use Flutter and be happy). It is really great tool. I am using it for about half year and there was no problem that Flutter can not to resolve.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, but I found the solution. So, how it works:

1. We have special static "Captcha" web page, hosted on domain, that authorized on our Firebase project. It simply shows `firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier`. User resolves captcha and it gives `token` string from response of callback.
2. On application login screen we show `WebBrowser` with "Captcha" page and listening url change event by `Linking` methods. On new url, we extract token string from it.
3. Then we create fake `firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier` object with `token` and pass it to `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber` (with phone number). SMS code will be sent.

I wrote tested simplest code below. You can directly "copy-paste" it. Just add firebase config (this config must be same for both) and set correct "Captcha" page url. Don't forget that phone must be entered in international format. In this code "Captcha" page hosted on firebase hosting, so it automatically initializing by including `init.js` and authorized by default.

**"Captcha" page** (hosted on firebase hosting):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Entering captcha</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em;">Please, enter captcha for continue<p/>

    <script src="/__/firebase/5.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/5.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script>

        function getToken(callback) {
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            container.id = 'captcha';
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            var captcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('captcha', {
                'size': 'normal',
                'callback': function(token) {
                    callback(token);
                },
                'expired-callback': function() {
                    callback('');
                }
            });
            captcha.render().then(function() {
                captcha.verify();
            });
        }

        function sendTokenToApp(token) {
            var baseUri = decodeURIComponent(location.search.replace(/^\?appurl\=/, ''));
            location.href = baseUri + '/?token=' + encodeURIComponent(token);
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            getToken(sendTokenToApp);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Auth screen in expo project**:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {Text, View, ScrollView, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native'
import {Linking, WebBrowser} from 'expo'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'

const captchaUrl = `https://my-firebase-hosting/captcha-page.html?appurl=${Linking.makeUrl('')}`

firebase.initializeApp({
    //firebase config
});

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            user: undefined,
            phone: '',
            confirmationResult: undefined,
            code: ''
        }
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            this.setState({user})
        })
    }

    onPhoneChange = (phone) => {
        this.setState({phone})
    }
    onPhoneComplete = async () => {
        let token = null
        const listener = ({url}) => {
            WebBrowser.dismissBrowser()
            const tokenEncoded = Linking.parse(url).queryParams['token']
            if (tokenEncoded)
                token = decodeURIComponent(tokenEncoded)
        }
        Linking.addEventListener('url', listener)
        await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(captchaUrl)
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', listener)
        if (token) {
            const {phone} = this.state
            //fake firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier
            const captchaVerifier = {
                type: 'recaptcha',
                verify: () => Promise.resolve(token)
            }
            try {
                const confirmationResult = await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone, captchaVerifier)
                this.setState({confirmationResult})
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e)
            }

        }
    }
    onCodeChange = (code) => {
        this.setState({code})
    }
    onSignIn = async () => {
        const {confirmationResult, code} = this.state
        try {
            await confirmationResult.confirm(code)
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e)
        }
        this.reset()
    }
    onSignOut = async () => {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signOut()
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e)
        }
    }
    reset = () => {
        this.setState({
            phone: '',
            phoneCompleted: false,
            confirmationResult: undefined,
            code: ''
        })
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.user)
            return (
                <ScrollView style={{padding: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
                    <Text>You signed in</Text>
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.onSignOut}
                        title="Sign out"
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            )

        if (!this.state.confirmationResult)
            return (
                <ScrollView style={{padding: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.phone}
                        onChangeText={this.onPhoneChange}
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                        placeholder="Your phone"
                    />
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.onPhoneComplete}
                        title="Next"
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            )
        else
            return (
                <ScrollView style={{padding: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.code}
                        onChangeText={this.onCodeChange}
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        placeholder="Code from SMS"
                    />
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.onSignIn}
                        title="Sign in"
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the captcha page dismiss automatically once user does the verification?

Comment: @iAviator, Yes. Captcha invokes `callback` or `expired-callback`, then page redirects by setting `location.href`, finally, this url changing detects by listener function (`Linking.addEventListener('url', listener)`)

Comment: Ok..also how can implement invisible captcha in react native where I want user should be verified without any interaction on screen?

Comment: WebBrowser modal screen anyway need to be shown, because it gives token string.
You can try to experiment with Recaptcha modes https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#use-invisible-recaptcha

Comment: The issue im facing now is the web browser screen sometimes doesn't show the verify images grid and only shows the recaptcha checkbox.

Comment: hmm, never faced with that. what's device model?

Comment: The pop up was not closing it was on index.html of firebase hosting, I change it to captcha.html and now it works

Comment: @Rinat So this works in iOS but not in Android. In android, the pop does not close. Did you manage to make it work in Android?

Comment: fake firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier not work anymore. I see this error message : Error: An implementation of firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier.prototype.verify() must return a firebase.Promise that resolves with a string.

Comment: @boygiandi, what version of firebase do you use? maybe version downgrading (for example to 5.3.1) will help, or you can try return firebase own promise object instead of native promise (by fixing it there: `() => Promise.resolve(token)`)

Comment: It worked well when I downloaded your project and changed changed the captcha url.In My project I linked react and react native to same firebase project.so i hosted a single page app.my question is where i host captcha.html?

Comment: Above problem got solved.It worked well on expo client.It worked well when i published to expo too.But when i build the apk file and installed on real device,the app get closed suddenly showing deep link error no custom scheme.So I added "scheme":'myapp' in app.json file.Now the App opens,captacha page loads after i ticked it goes to my app,but loads the field to enter mobile number with the mobile number i have already added.I get otp from firebase.But the phone number field loads insted of otp entering field.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution, based on @Rinat's one.
Main issue with the previous code is `firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber` never trigger as it's not in the webView, and firebase >6.3.3 requires a valid domain for authentication.
I decided to use [React Native Webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) to make communication between WebView and Native more easy.

**React-Native side**

```
import React from 'react'
import { KeyboardAvoidingView  } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput, Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

firebase.initializeApp({
    //...your firebase config
});

const captchaUrl = 'https://yourfirebasehosting/captcha.html';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            phoneNumber: '',
            phoneSubmitted: false,
            promptSmsCode: false,
            smsCode: '',
            smsCodeSubmitted: false
        }
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);
    }

    onAuthStateChanged = async user => {
        if (user) {
            const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
            if (token) {
                // User is fully logged in, with JWT in token variable
            }
        }
    }

    updatePhoneNumber = phoneNumber => this.setState({phoneNumber});
    updateSmsCode = smsCode => this.setState({smsCode});

    onSubmitPhoneNumber = () => this.setState({phoneSubmitted: true});

    onGetMessage = async event => {
        const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
        const message = event.nativeEvent.data;

        switch (message) {
            case "DOMLoaded":
                this.webviewRef.injectJavaScript(`getToken('${phoneNumber}')`);
                return;
            case "ErrorSmsCode":
                // SMS Not sent or Captcha verification failed. You can do whatever you want here
                return;
            case "":
                return;
            default: {
                this.setState({
                    promptSmsCode: true,
                    verificationId: message,
                })
            }
        }
    }

    onSignIn = async () => {
        this.setState({smsCodeSubmitted: true});
        const { smsCode, verificationId } = this.state;
        const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, smsCode);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
    }

    render() {

        const { phoneSubmitted, phoneNumber, promptSmsCode, smsCode, smsCodeSubmitted } = this.state;

        if (!phoneSubmitted) return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
                <TextInput
                    label='Phone Number'
                    value={phoneNumber}
                    onChangeText={this.updatePhoneNumber}
                    mode="outlined"
                />
                <Button mode="contained" onPress={this.onSubmitPhoneNumber}>
                    Send me the code!
                </Button>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView >
        );

        if (!promptSmsCode) return (
            <WebView
                ref={r => (this.webviewRef = r)}
                source={{ uri: captchaUrl }}
                onMessage={this.onGetMessage}
            />
        )

        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
                <TextInput
                    label='Verification code'
                    value={smsCode}
                    onChangeText={this.updateSmsCode}
                    mode="outlined"
                    disabled={smsCodeSubmitted}
                    keyboardType='numeric'
                />
                <Button mode="contained" onPress={this.onSignIn} disabled={smsCodeSubmitted}>
                    Send
                </Button>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView >
        );
    }
}
```

**captcha.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Entering captcha</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="/__/firebase/6.3.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/6.3.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getToken(phoneNumber) {
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            container.id = 'captcha';
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('captcha', {
                'size': 'normal',
                'callback': function(response) {
                    var appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
                    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
                        .then(function (confirmationResult) {
                            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(confirmationResult.verificationId);
                        }).catch(function (error) {
                            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('ErrorSmsCode');
                        });
                }
            });

            window.recaptchaVerifier.render().then(function() {
                window.recaptchaVerifier.verify();
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('DOMLoaded');
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok @Rinat's answer was almost perfect.

There is problem with this function in the captcha page

```
function sendTokenToApp(token) {
  var baseUri = decodeURIComponent(location.search.replace(/^\?appurl\=/, ''));
  location.href = baseUri + '/?token=' + encodeURIComponent(token);
}
```

It works with iOS (Safary), but it turns that Chrome does not allow

```
location.href
```

of custom URLs (we were trying to redirect the user to a custom URL, exp://192.12.12.31)

So this is the new function:

```
function sendTokenToApp(token) {
            var baseUri = decodeURIComponent(location.search.replace(/^\?appurl\=/, ''));
            const finalUrl = location.href = baseUri + '/?token=' + encodeURIComponent(token);
            const continueBtn = document.querySelector('#continue-btn');
            continueBtn.onclick = (event)=>{
                window.open(finalUrl,'_blank')
            }
            continueBtn.style.display = "block";
}
```

Of course you have to add a button in the HTML, so you can click on it.

This is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Entering captcha</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p style="text-align: center; font-size: 1.2em;">Please, enter captcha for continue<p/>
    <button id="continue-btn" style="display:none">Continue to app</button>

    <script src="/__/firebase/5.3.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/5.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    <script>

        function getToken(callback) {
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            container.id = 'captcha';
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            var captcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('captcha', {
                'size': 'normal',
                'callback': function(token) {
                    callback(token);
                },
                'expired-callback': function() {
                    callback('');
                }
            });
            captcha.render().then(function() {
                captcha.verify();
            });
        }

        function sendTokenToApp(token) {
            var baseUri = decodeURIComponent(location.search.replace(/^\?appurl\=/, ''));
            const finalUrl = location.href = baseUri + '/?token=' + encodeURIComponent(token);
            const continueBtn = document.querySelector('#continue-btn');
            continueBtn.onclick = (event)=>{
                window.open(finalUrl,'_blank')
            }
            continueBtn.style.display = "block";
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            getToken(sendTokenToApp);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This took me almost 7 hours to figure it out so I hope it helps someone!

**Edit after production:**

Don't forget to add **"scheme": "appName"**, to app.json of expo app or browser wont open since deep link problem.

Read this

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking#in-a-standalone-app

Answer (score 2):

I made the functional equivelant with state hooks based on Damian Buchet version. The captcha page is same. The React native module:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Text, View, TextInput, Button,StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import firebase from '../../components/utils/firebase'  /contains firebase initiation


const captchaUrl = 'https://my-domain.web.app/captcha-page.html';

const LoginScreenPhone = props => {
const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState();
const [step, setStep] = useState('initial');
const [smsCode, setSmsCode] = useState();
const [verificationId, setVerificationId]=useState();

const onAuthStateChanged = async user => {
    if (user) {
        const token = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
        if (token) {
            // User is fully logged in, with JWT in token variable
        }
    }
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);



const onGetMessage = async event => {

    const message = event.nativeEvent.data;
    console.log(message);
    switch (message) {
        case "DOMLoaded":

            return;
        case "ErrorSmsCode":
            // SMS Not sent or Captcha verification failed. You can do whatever you want here
            return;
        case "":
            return;
        default: {
            setStep('promptSmsCode');
            setVerificationId(message);
            }
        }
}


const onSignIn = async () => {
    setStep('smsCodeSubmitted');
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, smsCode);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
    props.navigation.navigate('Home');
}

return (
    <View>
    {step==='initial' && (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView  behavior="padding" enabled>
            <TextInput
                label='Phone Number'
                value={phoneNumber}
                onChangeText={phone =>setPhoneNumber(phone)}
                mode="outlined"
            />
            <Button mode="contained" onPress={()=>setStep('phoneSubmitted')} title=' Send me the code!'>

            </Button>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView >
    )}

  {step==='phoneSubmitted' && (
        <View style={{flex:1, minHeight:800}}>
            <Text>{`getToken('${phoneNumber}')`}</Text>
        <WebView
         injectedJavaScript={`getToken('${phoneNumber}')`}          
            source={{ uri: captchaUrl }}
            onMessage={onGetMessage}
        />
        </View>
    )}

   {step==='promptSmsCode' && (<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>
            <TextInput
                label='Verification code'
                value={smsCode}
                onChangeText={(sms)=>setSmsCode(sms)}
                mode="outlined"
                keyboardType='numeric'
            />
            <Button mode="contained" onPress={onSignIn} title='Send'>

            </Button>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView >)}
    </View>
);
}


export default LoginScreenPhone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks For solutions .. Worked for me .. 
But for more better way we can skip captcha by adding invisible captcha verifier

// React Native Side

```
     import * as React from 'react'
    import { View, ScrollView, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, WebView } from 'react-native';
    import { Text } from "galio-framework";
    import { Linking } from 'expo';
    import * as firebase from 'firebase';
    import OTPInputView from '@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input'
    import theme from '../constants/Theme';

    const captchaUrl = `your firebase host /index.html?appurl=${Linking.makeUrl('')}`

    firebase.initializeApp({
        //firebase config

    });

    export default class PhoneAUth extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                user: undefined,
                phone: '',
                confirmationResult: undefined,
                code: '',
                isWebView: false
            }
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                this.setState({ user })
            })
        }

    onPhoneChange = (phone) => {
        this.setState({ phone })
    }
    _onNavigationStateChange(webViewState) {
        console.log(webViewState.url)
        this.onPhoneComplete(webViewState.url)
    }
    onPhoneComplete = async (url) => {
        let token = null
        console.log("ok");
        //WebBrowser.dismissBrowser()
        const tokenEncoded = Linking.parse(url).queryParams['token']
        if (tokenEncoded)
            token = decodeURIComponent(tokenEncoded)

        this.verifyCaptchaSendSms(token);


    }
    verifyCaptchaSendSms = async (token) => {
        if (token) {
            const { phone } = this.state
            //fake firebase.auth.ApplicationVerifier
            const captchaVerifier = {
                type: 'recaptcha',
                verify: () => Promise.resolve(token)
            }
            try {
                const confirmationResult = await firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone, captchaVerifier)
                console.log("confirmationResult" + JSON.stringify(confirmationResult));
                this.setState({ confirmationResult, isWebView: false })
            } catch (e) {
                console.warn(e)
            }

        }
    }

    onSignIn = async (code) => {
        const { confirmationResult } = this.state
        try {
            const result = await confirmationResult.confirm(code);
            this.setState({ result });

        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e)

        }
    }
    onSignOut = async () => {
        try {
            await firebase.auth().signOut()
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e)
        }
    }
    reset = () => {
        this.setState({
            phone: '',
            phoneCompleted: false,
            confirmationResult: undefined,
            code: ''
        })
    }

    render() {
    if (this.state.user)
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{padding: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
                <Text>You signed in</Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.onSignOut}
                    title="Sign out"
                />
            </ScrollView>
        )
        else if (this.state.isWebView)
            return (
                <WebView
                    ref="webview"
                    source={{ uri: captchaUrl }}
                    onNavigationStateChange={this._onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
                    javaScriptEnabled={true}
                    domStorageEnabled={true}
                    injectedJavaScript={this.state.cookie}
                    startInLoadingState={false}
                />

            )
        else if (!this.state.confirmationResult)
            return (
                <ScrollView style={{ padding: 20, marginTop: 20 }}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.phone}
                        onChangeText={this.onPhoneChange}
                        keyboardType="phone-pad"
                        placeholder="Your phone"
                    />
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.onPhoneComplete}
                        title="Next"
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            )
        else
            return (
                <ScrollView style={{padding: 20, marginTop: 20}}>
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.code}
                        onChangeText={this.onCodeChange}
                        keyboardType="numeric"
                        placeholder="Code from SMS"
                    />
                    <Button
                        onPress={this.onSignIn}
                        title="Sign in"
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    borderStyleBase: {
        width: 30,
        height: 45
    },

    borderStyleHighLighted: {
        borderColor: theme.COLORS.PRIMARY,
    },

    underlineStyleBase: {
        width: 30,
        height: 45,
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
    },

    underlineStyleHighLighted: {
        borderColor: theme.COLORS.PRIMARY,
    },
});
```

// Captcha Side . I used Firebase Hosting to host this file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Firebase Phone Authentication</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.3.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        var firebaseConfig = {
    // config
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.3.0/firebaseui.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.3.0/firebaseui.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
    <script>

        function getToken(callback) {
            var container = document.createElement('div');
            container.id = 'captcha';
            document.body.appendChild(container);
            var captcha = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('captcha', {

        /****************
         I N V I S I B L E  
        **********************/
                'size': 'invisible',
                'callback': function (token) {
                    callback(token);
                },
                'expired-callback': function () {
                    callback('');
                }
            });
            captcha.render().then(function () {
                captcha.verify();
            });
        }

        function sendTokenToApp(token) {
            var baseUri = decodeURIComponent(location.search.replace(/^\?appurl\=/, ''));
            location.href = 'http://www.google.com + '/?token=' + encodeURIComponent(token);
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            getToken(sendTokenToApp);
        });

    </script>
    <h2>Verification Code is Sending !! </h2>
    <h3>Please Wait !!</h3>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In android dismiss web browser doesn't support. So I found more better way by using webview it worked for me on android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

**Doorman** provides Firebase phone auth support for Expo apps without detaching. It also comes with customizable UI components for Expo/React Native.

Link: https://doorman.cool

The code sample looks something like this:

```js
export default withPhoneAuth(App, {
  doorman: {
    publicProjectId: "ID here"
  }
})
```